# Plotting heatmap for two scalar values with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, heatmap, seaborn

I'm trying to plot the relationship of two independent variables `x` and `y` with a dependent variable `score` as a heatmap: `x` and `y` are integer values from 0 to infinity and `score` is a real value between 0 and 1.

### Desired appearance

There are a large number of seen values for `x` and `y`, so I would like to  have it look more like a typical density plot like the example below, since the exact values for each individual `(x, y)` are not of great importance:

[image: Example desired output]

*(example taken from [Seaborn's documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html))*

### Current approach

Currently, I'm trying to use Seaborn's [`heatmap(..)`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) function to plot the data, but the resulting plot is almost unreadable, with a large amount of space between each discrete data point rather than a "continuous" gradient. The logic for plotting used is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

df = read_df_using_pandas(...)
table = df.pivot_table(
    values="score",
    index="y",
    columns="x", aggfunc='mean')
ax = sns.heatmap(table, cmap=cm.magma_r)
ax.invert_yaxis()
fig = sns_plot.get_figure()
fig.savefig("some_outfile.png", format="png")
```

The result plot looks like the following, **which is wrong, as it does not match the desired appearance described in the section above**:
[image: Heatmap produced by code]

**I do not know why there is a large amount of space between each discrete data point rather than a "continuous" gradient.** How can I plot the relationship between my data composed of two discrete values (`x` and `y`) which is represented as a third, scalar value (`score`), in a way which mimics the style of a gradient density plot? The solution need not use either Seaborn or even matplotlib.

Comment: Please make your case reproducible, see [mcve].

Comment: This is minimal: The only thing the code does is make the plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use imshow

an example that works for me, where 'toplot' is a matrix containing the values you want the heatmap for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
plt.clf()        

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
toplot = INSERT MATRIX HERE
res = ax.imshow(toplot, cmap=plt.cm.viridis, vmin = 0)    
cb = fig.colorbar(res,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)


plt.title('Heatmap')

plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')

row = np.where(toplot == toplot.max())[0][0]
column= np.where(toplot == toplot.max())[1][0]

plt.plot(column,row,'*')

plt.savefig('plots/heatmap.png', format='png')
```

I also added a star, indicating the highest point in the plot, which I needed.

Comment: If you used `heatmap` instead of `imshow` in this example, the plot would look similar, right? It would not look like the segmented plot shown in the question. While the question is sufficiently unclear about the input data, I somehow doubt that simply using `imshow` solves this unknown issue. Sometimes questions cannot be answered with the information given in the question.

Comment: I just tested @errantlinguist code. Works fine with my matrix. Maybe the pandas data was not converted properly?

Comment: @Alex what does your test data look like, e.g. in terms of dtypes for the columns?

Comment: I'm using an array of float64

Comment: @Alex mine also uses float64; Now I'm even more confused. Are you also using `pivot_table(..)`?

Comment: @errantlinguist That is funny; you are answering my attempt to help here by blantly offending me; yet judging from the fact that you asked the user who answered this question for his input data you even acknowlege yourself that it indeed depends on the input data. Not sure how I would call people that expect something from others that they are themselves not willing to provide, but you gave some options three comments above.

Comment: No, no pivot table, just a table with values. 

And be nice :)

Comment: this code works:

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.pyplot import cm

import seaborn as sns


sns.set_style("whitegrid")


table = np.array([[2,3,4],[3,4,2],[1,3,5]])
ax = sns.heatmap(table, cmap=cm.magma_r)

So i think something is wrong with the way you import it via pandas